# Click Menu and Refresh Json [IONIC]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I wish to have side menu with the list of chapters, eg: chap1, chap2..chap10. How to change the content if I click on chap1, the content will show chap1's content? The content is retrieve from a JSON file.

//route

```
.state('chapter', {
        url: '/chapter/:aId',
        templateUrl: 'templates/chapters.html',
        controller: 'ChapterController'
    })
```

//controller

```
.controller('ChapterController', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $ionicSideMenuDelegate){

    $http.get('js/bb.json').success(function(data){

        $scope.chapters = data.bb;

        $scope.imagesArray = [];
        data.bb.forEach(function (item) {
            if(item.chapter == $stateParams.aId){
                item.images.forEach(function (image) {
                    $scope.imagesArray.push({
                        src: image
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('image-viewer').update();

        $scope.reloadChap = function(){
            $scope.imagesArray = [];
            data.bible.forEach(function (item) {
                // console.log($stateParams);
                if(item.chapter == $stateParams.aId){
                    item.images.forEach(function (image) {
                        $scope.imagesArray.push({
                            src: image
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

My problem here is when I click chap2, the content wont change to chap2's content but the url above has change to '/chapter/2'.

Millions thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so say your json looks like this

```
$scope.chapters = [{chapter 1: 'text', number: '1'}, {chapter 2: 'text', number: '2'}];
```

in the side menu you want to show all the chapters that can be clicked on

```
<ion-side-menu side="right" ng-click="showChapterContent($index)">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="chapter in chapters">
        {{chapter.number}}
    </div>
</ion-side-menu>
```

See in the ng-click funciton, that will pass in the index of whatever chapter you click on. so then you have you ion side menu content.

```
<ion-side-menu-content>
  {{chapterContent}}
  </ion-side-menu-content>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.showChapterContent = function(index){
    $scope.chapterContent = $scope.chapters[index].chapter;
};
```

Then when you click on the chapter in the side menu it will grab the appropriate text from the json file and display it in the middle content of the page.